# Selecting a Confidence Level equal to or greater than 70% in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I am writing a Google Earth Engine script and I want to calculate the Burn Area of my study area. However, I only want to select a burn area that has a confidence level equal to or greater than 70%.

This is the script that I am using and I would want assistance on how to filter the ConfidenceLevel greater than 70

```
var zimbabwe = ee.FeatureCollection('users/am/zimbabwe')
Map.addLayer(zimbabwe)
print(zimbabwe)
print()
Map.centerObject(zimbabwe, 6);

// Visualize FireCCI51 for the year 2019
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('ESA/CCI/FireCCI/5_1')
                  .filterDate('2019-01-01', '2019-12-31')
                  .filterBounds(zimbabwe)
                  .filter(ee.Filter.lt('ConfidenceLevel',70))
var burnedArea_Confidence_70 = dataset.select('BurnDate');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make a function to mask an image based on its `ConfidenceLevel` band. Then `map` that function over the `ImageCollection` to mask each image

```js
var zimbabwe = ee.FeatureCollection('users/amazhindu/zimbabwe')

Map.centerObject(zimbabwe, 10);

// Visualize FireCCI51 for the year 2019
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('ESA/CCI/FireCCI/5_1')
                  .filterDate('2019-01-01', '2019-12-31')
                  .filterBounds(zimbabwe);

// make a function to mask images based on the ConfidenceLevel band                  
var filterConfidence = function(image){
  var mask = image.select('ConfidenceLevel').gt(70);
  return image.updateMask(mask);
};

// map over the image collection and apply the mask
var confidentDataset = dataset.map(filterConfidence);

// original pixels
var burnedArea = dataset.select('BurnDate');

// pixels with confidence > 70
var burnedArea_Confidence_70 = confidentDataset.select('BurnDate');

// visualise image collections for comparison
Map.addLayer(burnedArea, {palette:['0000ff']}, 'burned area');
Map.addLayer(burnedArea_Confidence_70, {palette:['ff0000']}, 'burned area confidence >70');

// add region of interest as a transparent polygon
Map.addLayer(zimbabwe.style({fillColor:'00000000'}), null, 'Zimbabwe');
```

In the visualisation, blue pixels represent the original data and red pixels represent a confidence level > 70.

[image]

Keep in mind that `burnedArea_Confidence_70` is still an *ImageCollection* and what is being displayed is all 12 images (1 for each month of the year).

Comment: Thank you so much. This is just perfect